# VBScript Regular Expressions to check IP address validity with some adtional characters

Tags: vbscript

How to create VB script Irregular expression syntax to check the VPparam (IP address validity)
When the last octatat of the IP address is a range between ip's (x-y)
and between each IP we can put the "," separator in order to add another IP

example of VBparam

VBparam=172.17.202.1-20

VBparam=172.17.202.1-10,192.9.200.1-100

VBparam=172.17.202.1-10,192.9.200.1-100,180.1.1.1-20

THX
yael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cscript test.vbs

Updated: to verify the range of the IP: 1-255

Updated: fixed matching end of line

```
Dim strByteMatch, strIpMatch, strPattern 
strByteMatch = "(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)"
strIpMatch = strByteMatch & "\." & strByteMatch & "\." & strByteMatch & _
"\.(" & strByteMatch & "|(" & strByteMatch & "-" & strByteMatch & "))"
strPattern = "^" & strIpMatch & "(," & strIpMatch & ")*$"


Test "172.17.202.1-20", strPattern
Test "172.17.202.1-10,192.9.200.1-100", strPattern
Test "172.17.202.1-10,192.9.200.1-100,180.1.1.1-20", strPattern
Test "172.17.202.1bug-20", strPattern            ' This should fail
Test "172.17.202.333,172.17.202.1", strPattern   ' This should fail

Sub Test(strString, strPattern)
    if RegExIsMatch(strString, strPattern) Then
        WScript.Echo "Test Pass"
    else
        WScript.Echo "Test Fail"
    end if
End Sub

Function RegExIsMatch(strString,strPattern)
    Dim RegEx
    RegExMatch=False

    Set RegEx = New RegExp                
    RegEx.IgnoreCase = True                
    RegEx.Global=True                   
    RegEx.Pattern=strPattern

    If RegEx.Test(strString) Then RegExIsMatch=True
End Function
```

Comment: THX 
but I check the RE seems that its not verify the range of the IP:
1-254 , can we add this rule?

Comment: OK its check fine the first IP but if we have: 172.17.202.1-10,192.9.200.1-100,180.1.1.1-20  IP How we can improve the syntax to verify the second or third IP?? because its not check the second or th

Comment: another thing its not fail on: 172.17.202.1bug-20 (for example) whay?

Comment: excellent RE you wrote , I tested the regular E and its work on all
scenarios , 
THX for your help
yael